# Process only input fields whose values have been modified?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there any easier way to set to process only those input fields within a h:form whose values have *actually* been changed at the client side ignoring those that havent changed?

---

Using JSF 2.2 with
Primefaces 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in JSF 2.2, nor in PrimeFaces 3.2.

Closest what you can get is PrimeFaces 3.3 (currently only available as snapshot) with [new client ID selector syntax](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1867) which is borrowed from the jQuery selector API. Unfortunately, this doesn't support some `:changed` selector (even already not in jQuery selector API).

This is not exactly trivial to implement and integrate in PrimeFaces JS API. You basically need to hook a `change` listener on every single input element in the background wherein you collect client IDs of those who have been changed.